# How to find the number of times the ODE's derivative is called in one invocation.

Tags: python-2.7, ode

I am using Python to do exercise about numerical integration of ODE. I encounter with this problem.

"During each single run of the ODE integrator (i.e., one invocation of the
integrate(t)method), the integrator internally divides the time interval into many discrete steps, and runs the specified scheme (such as Runge-Kutta) using those steps. Let us investigate how many times the ODE's derivative function gets called during this process."

Does there exist any method to find the number of times?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function that you pass to the integrator you can write some code that will collect that statistics for you. For example, instead of

```
def f(t, x):
    return -2 * x
```

write

```
class F:

    def __init__(self):
        self.calls = 0

    def __call__(t, x):
        self.calls += 1
        return -2 * x
```

and then pass an object of this class to the integrator, e.g. (schematically)

```
f = F()
r = ode(f, jac)
r.integrate(tmax)
print(f.calls)
```